# Is it possible to integrate Wordpress CMS with a telephone system such as Asterisk?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, integration, asterisk

At the moment, I am dealing with a Web project and would like to know what are the possibilities to develop a Website with Wordpress CMS and integrate it with a Telephone system such as Asterisk. The main purpose is to build a portal where visitors can make calls to others. Any idea on this?

All your opinions/responses are welcome! I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a paid product then check out [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) also check out [Asterix PHP API](http://code.google.com/p/asterisk-php-api/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I will have a look at the PHP Api, I guess Twilio operates for Canada and the U.S only. I'll find out if the operate in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is -very- vague.  If you mean "I click / you call" service, then yes.

Essentially Asterisk PBX support API calls via HTTP/REST as well as "AGI", which is the same as a website CGI, only for Asterisk.

Really, the limit is pretty much what you can imagine.  If you ask a more specific question, I can provide a more specific answer.